# How to validate DropdownButtomFormFeild in flutter using formkey

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter I am trying to create a large form, where I am using form key to validate form and global object to store value using on Saved method on TextFormFeild of flutter how can i do same thing with DropdownButtonFormField.

Specifically, i don't want to use DropdownButtonFormFeild onChanged method instead i want to do it using onSaved method.

Comment: Can you provide the some code snippets that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String? selectedItem;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    formKey.currentState?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                value: selectedItem,
                hint: const Text("Select"),
                items: const <String>[
                  "A",
                  "B",
                ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                  (String value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value),
                    );
                  },
                ).toList(),
                onSaved: (String? value) {
                  selectedItem = value;
                  setState(() {});
                },
                validator: (String? value) {
                  return value == null ? "Required" : null;
                },
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
                    // Valid form
                  } else {
                    // Invalid form
                  }
                },
                child: const Text("Submit"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `validator` on `TextFormField`, then you can use it on `DropdownButtonFormField` too.

Wrap with `Form`, add `formKey` then just trigger the validation with the button.

**Example:**

```dart
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
  items: items,
  onChanged: onChanged,
  validator: (value) {
    if (value == null){
      return "ERROR";
    }
    return null ; 
  },
),
```

You can use `validator` as same as in `TextFormField`.